# Jquery axax request doesn't execute callbacks

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have deleted the ajax function from my code and still get page reload. My error is elsewhere. Sorry.

Please treat this issue as closed.

---

I am using jquery ajax to get json data from a php server program after user clicks on an element.

When I execute the ajax request, I see in firebug that the message is sent to the server and that valid json is requrned. However none of the three callbacks is executed. (When I step through the code the "req1.always" is executed but not the "console.log").

Back in the calling routine, a few statements later, a jquery call which normally works causes the page to reload!

I'm tearing my hair out and would appreciate any help.

```
function displayCanvasList() {
  var req1 = $.ajax({
    url: lServerLocation + "testserver.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
      action: "get",
      },
    dataType: 'json'
  });
  console.log ("Sent get request");
  req1.done(function( data ) {
    console.log("Get request done");
  });
  req1.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    console.log( "Get request failed " + textStatus );
  });
  req1.always(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    console.log( "Get request complete " + textStatus );
  });
}
```

Comment: if your problem is page reload then you should look at the element which is clicked. please post the html as well.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I have deleted this function from the code and still get page reload. My error is elsewhere.

Comment: The issue was the element which triggered the ajax call ... I used an input type = submit in a form (when I was handling the form functionality manually). Changing to input type = button resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
var req1 = $.ajax({
        url: lServerLocation + "testserver.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
          action: "get",
          },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response){console.log('boop')}
      });
```